# Xamarin and SQLite: an item with the same key has already been added. key: 3

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like to make some preliminary remarks: I have a lot of project that it's working with the same code but previous version of SQLite (usually 1.2) and I don't have `.NET Core`.

I've created a new `Xamarin` project and I added the latest version of `sqlite-net-pcl` [1.3.3](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). I noticed in my project now there is `.NET Core`. I defined an entity

```
public interface ITableEntityMyExpenses {
    int Id { get; set; }
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then a `BaseTable`

```
public class BaseTableMyExpenses : ITableEntityMyExpenses {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    [Indexed]
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

And then a table

```
public class Expense : BaseTableMyExpenses {
    public DateTime ExpenseDate { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

At the first time the app creates correctly the database. The database is empty.

[image: Structure]

[image: Empty]

If I try to add a new record in the database I receive this error:

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 3
>
> (TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)    at SQLite.EnumCacheInfo..ctor(Type
>   type)    at SQLite.EnumCache.GetInfo(Type type)    at
>   SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BindParameter(sqlite3_stmt stmt, Int32 index,
>   Object value, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)    at
>   SQLite.PreparedSqlLiteInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Object[] source)
>   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Insert(Object obj, String extra, Type
>   objType)    at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Insert(Object obj)    at
>   MyExpenses.Repository.MyExpensesDatabase.SaveItem[T](T item)    at
>   MyExpenses.Repository.MyExpensesRepository.SaveExpense(Expense item)
>   at MyExpenses.ViewModels.ExpenseItemViewModel.SaveExpenseOnDB()    at
>   MyExpenses.ViewModels.ExpenseItemViewModel.d__42.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   MyExpenses.ViewModels.ExpenseItemViewModel.<b__41_0>d.MoveNext()

What is wrong?

I also tried to update an old project to the new version on SQLite. In this case apparently everything is working fine but if I try to execute this code

```
public List<T> GetItems<T>() where T : ITableEntity, new()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        return (from i in database.Table<T>()
                select i).ToList();
    }
}

public T GetItem<T>(int id) where T : ITableEntity, new()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        return database.Table<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

I receive another kind of error

> Cannot compile: Parameter

[image: SQLite error]

> at SQLite.TableQuery1.CompileExpr(Expression expr, List1 queryArgs) at
>   SQLite.TableQuery1.CompileExpr(Expression expr, List1 queryArgs) at
>   SQLite.TableQuery1.CompileExpr(Expression expr, List1 queryArgs) at
>   SQLite.TableQuery1.CompileExpr(Expression expr, List1 queryArgs) at
>   SQLite.TableQuery1.GenerateCommand(String selectionList) at
>   SQLite.TableQuery1.GetEnumerator() at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source) at
>   SQLite.TableQuery1.FirstOrDefault() at
>   SQLite.TableQuery1.FirstOrDefault(Expression1 predExpr) at
>   MyExpenses.Repository.MyExpensesDatabase.GetItem[T](Int32 id) at
>   MyExpenses.Repository.MyExpensesRepository.GetExpense(Int32 id) at
>   MyExpenses.ViewModels.ExpenseItemViewModel.LoadData() at
>   MyExpenses.ViewModels.ExpenseItemViewModel..ctor(Int32 expenseId,
>   Boolean SaveOnDatabase) at
>   MyExpenses.Views.ExpenseItem.LoadViewModel(Int32 expenseId) at
>   MyExpenses.Views.ExpenseItem..ctor(Int32 expenseId) at
>   MyExpenses.Views.ExpenseList.OnEdit(Object sender, EventArgs e) at
>   Xamarin.Forms.MenuItem.OnClicked() at
>   Xamarin.Forms.MenuItem.Xamarin.Forms.IMenuItemController.Activate() at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.MenuItemCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ICommandToWinRTAdapter.Execute(Object
>   parameter)

**Update**

I added a new record in the database with a common function:

```
public int SaveItem<T>(T item) where T : ITableEntityMyExpenses
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        if (item.Id != 0)
        {
            database.Update(item);
            return item.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            return database.Insert(item);
        }
    }
}
```

If I change

```
public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
```

with

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you explain/show _how_ you're adding a new record to the database? You've marked that `Id` field with `AutoIncrement`, so telling the database to use a specific value for the `id` column might cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

After the update of `Xamarin Forms` and `SQLite-net-pcl`, something definitely changed. Most of the functions are working fine but not that

```
public T GetItem<T>(int id) where T : ITableEntity, new()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        return database.Table<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

You have to change your code like that:

```
public T GetItem<T>(int id) where T : ITableEntity, new()
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        return database.Table<T>().Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```